# C++ execute same code on all files in a folder

Tags: c++, boost, directory

I have been surfing the net for really long time and I didn't even get close to any solution to this. Sorry if it seems trivial to experts.

I have a C++ code that takes a binary file as an input argument, does some computation then outputs a `.csv` file. 
So, I have been using the command line to execute the code over one or more files, as following

```
MyProgram filename1 filename2
```

In my case, I have all my files from `filename1` to `filenameN` in a specific folder. 
I want to know if there is any way to input the folder name, so the program would be executed over all the files included.

Maybe something like this

```
Myprogram /Users/Whatever
```

or in windows like

```
Myprogram C:\User\Whatever
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Considered using a loop in the code?

Comment: Use [**Boost.Filesystem**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to iterate through the given directory. C++17 will have a filesystem as part of `std`

Comment: @CinCout I don't have an idea of how using the loop from inside the code would help reading unknown number of files in a folder. Would you give me any ideas for this please?

Comment: @WhiZTiM I tried installing boost and configuring it. But I ended with really more complicated issues. Like not finding the file or even something like (undefined symbols for architecture x86_64).
I am even more lost now!

Answer (score 1):

For linux you can use command line with wild characters arguments like: `YourProgram path/to/*.csv` and you'll get all files match to the pattern `path/to/*.csv` into the argv array.

If it is windows you can use some Win API like [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) to resolve the wild characters and get all match files. [you can also check this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx):

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I mentioned in my question, all my files are binary files, so they don't have any extension. When I try the wild characters for the linux, it only reads the first file.

Comment: On linux you'll get the 1st arg in `argv[1]` the 2nd in `argv[2]` and so on. you'll need to loop all arguments `for (i=1; i<argc; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

On *nix based consoles then the "xargs" command is your friend. e.g.

`find ./MyDirectory -name "*.notcsv" | xargs myprogram`

Personally I wouldn't modify the code itself to iterate through files as the operating system supplies a mechanism. It makes your program more "single responsibility". If you send the output to stdout/cout it allows your program to be chained with other text processing commands if necessary.

Cheers